# Update different columns in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to port over a concept that I use in Java code that I've used to SQL stored procedures and I'm not sure if it's possible.

Essentially, if I have a table with 10 columns I want to be able to update different combinations of columns from the same stored procedure each time. I.e. in Java I would pass a map containing the values that I want to update and iterate through them and update each key value in the cache.

This has the benefit of not having to change the method signature to include each column name and not having to have a large piece of code doing a null check on each variable to figure out if it should be updated or not. I'm not sure if this is possible or whether certain database servers are capable of it (i.e. PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL) or they're all capable of it but I just can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Can you post an example of the Java code so it is more clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This can be done using dynamic SQL in any of the DBMS you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the below procedure would work assuming a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyBigTable(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COLUMNA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    COLUMNB VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
 )

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateMyBigTable(@ID INT, @ColumnAValue VARCHAR(100)=NULL, @ColumnBValue VARCHAR(100)=NULL)
AS BEGIN
UPDATE MyBigTable
    SET COLUMNA = CASE WHEN @ColumnAValue IS NULL THEN COLUMNA ELSE @ColumnAValue END,
    COLUMNB = CASE WHEN @ColumnBValue IS NULL THEN COLUMNB ELSE @ColumnBValue END
WHERE ID = @ID
    AND ((COLUMNA <> @ColumnAValue AND @ColumnAValue IS NOT NULL) OR (COLUMNB <> @ColumnBValue AND @ColumnBValue IS NOT NULL));
END

GO
```

However, this doesn't actually enumerate through the fields which is what you were asking about.  That is difficult to do in SQL Server without getting into dynamic SQL.

Comment: In the second case, how do you distinguish between a column you want to set to NULL and a column whose value you don't want to change?

Comment: You're right.  I'll going to pull that out.  The solution becomes much more complex if you're going to allow NULLs because I suppose you'd have to get into barred values such as sending low ASCII characters.  Upon re-reading, either solution doesn't really work for the OPs stated case anyway which is asking for a way to loop over the columns.

Comment: If you do this, you actually update the values - even if with its own existing value. From memory, this causes the indexes to be recalculated so is slower than figuring out a conditional statement at the beginning.

Comment: The trouble is that you only really have two options - either you update a field at a time in separate UPDATE statements with separate guard clauses in the WHERE (at which point you really need to run the update in a transaction plus SQL Server has to repeat the work to go find the row you want each time), or you update all of the fields in a single statement and risk having to unnecessarily update non-clustered indexes.

Comment: One option would be to pass in a bitmask and use case statements in the set clause to check whether that bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance either use dynamic SQL or an IF statement with a SQL statement for each possible combination of query parameters.

If you can stomach making the IF statements for each possible solution, go with that - it's stable, secure and performant.

If you have too many parameters for this, use dynamic SQL - you can generate your dynamic SQL in the stored procedure or earlier, just be sure to avoid [SQL injection issues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Your problem is very similar to the [dynamic search](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) problem covered by Erland Sommarskog.

Performance-wise, SQL Server will create an execution plan for every possible dynamic query type so performance will be similarly as good as having an IF statement to select each possible SQL statement.

This is in stark contrast to using `COLUMNB = CASE WHEN @COLUMNB IS NULL THEN COLUMNB ELSE @COLUMNB END` which will have only one execution plan and thus frequently a poor execution plan (depending on your where clause and indexes in the DB) and poor performance.